# tJdbcOutput component Delay for Table insert in Talend 6.4

Tags: sql-server, bigdata, sql-insert, talend

I am using a one to one mapping for loading data into a MSsql server table.
This mapping is simple and contains only two components. tFileinputDelimited for reading and tJdBCoutput for inserting into table.
we are using a tJdbcoutput component to load data into table.
We have created the mapping in talend standard job as well as big data job.
Standard job is giving 10 minutes to load 2 Million records.
But Bigdata job is giving more than one hour for inserting into table.
In standard commit interval is available. we have set it as 20000 and batch size as 50000. In Bigdata job the commit interval is not available but batch size is available.

Can you help to increase the performance of the bigdata job.

[image]

Comment: Maybe it's because standard Talend job is generated in java code, while BigData job is generated in MapReduce code, so the performance is not the same.. Could you try with using a tJDBCConnection, and only doing a commit in the end (tJDBCCommit) ?

Comment: @iMezouar . Hi..thanks...we are creating Bigdata Spark Job. so i don't think jobs are created with mapReduce Framework. Also tJDBCCommit is not available in Bigdata Spark Jobs.